# Electron Packager On Windows Does Nothing

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

I have written a small app with Electron in Windows and have some functionality which inspects the registry for information about some software that is installed, and I need to run the app on another machine to test. So, I am trying to package my app.

Firstly, it is important to note that when I run `>electron .` in the root of my project, it runs without any issues.

I have tried manually packaging the app, by placing my app under the `resources\app` folder and running Electron.exe. It doesn't work. The Electron app starts up in task manager before exiting just as quickly. Without any errors or warnings. No dialogs or anything.

I have installed the electron-packager module, and tried to use that to package the app. However, it does nothing. There is no console output, it just sits there for a while before exiting. And when it exits, there is no packaged app. Nothing has changed. I tried electron-builder and got the same result.

I am new to node in general, so I suspect I am simply doing something wrong. This is my package.json (which I still don't fully understand the purpose of):

```
{
  "name": "welcome",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "electron .",
    "compile": "node .\\node_modules\\webpack\\bin\\webpack.js",
    "prep": "robocopy . releases\\app /XD node_modules releases blah /S /MIR /XF *.jsx \"webpack.config.js\" && robocopy node_modules\\winreg releases\\app && robocopy node_modules\\path releases\\app",
    "package": "asar pack .\\releases\\app .\\releases\\app.asar",
    "build": "electron-packager releases\\app WelcomeApp --ignore=node_modules --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --output=releases"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "babel": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.3.4",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^15.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.0",
    "winreg": "^1.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.13.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.13.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "electron-builder": "^5.34.1",
    "electron-packager": "^7.7.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1"
  }
}
```

My directory structure is as follows

```
Welcome
|____app
|     |____src
|     |     |____dist
|     |     |     |____bundle.js
|     |     |____react
|     |     |     |____components
|     |     |     |     |____installation.jsx
|     |     |     |     |____...
|     |     |     |     |____software.jsx
|     |     |     |____index.jsx
|     |     |____util
|     |           |____data.js
|     |____app.html
|____node_modules
|     |____...
|____main.js
|____package.json
|____webpack.config.js
```

There is no problem with what I am doing from what I can see. And like I said, when running with electron cli (`electron .`) it works perfectly fine. So, I am at a loss. I can only presume there is probably something wrong with the package.json. Is there an issue? Why am I not seeing any console output when running the packager?

Comment: You have a fairly complex directory structure. Since you are new to electron-packager, I would start with everything flat, as in the Quick Start app that's at electron.atom.io. Get that working first. (It works fine for me.) Then, start getting more elaborate with a more sophisticated tree structure.

Comment: did you tried to package your app using the API of electron-packager instead of using command lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'll leave you my script of how i package my application with the API of electron-packager, maybe you can build your.exe with this.

```
'use strict';
var packager = require('electron-packager');
var options = {
    'arch': 'ia32',
    'platform': 'win32',
    'dir': './',
    'app-copyright': 'Paulo Galdo',
    'app-version': '2.1.6',
    'asar': true,
    'icon': './app.ico',
    'name': 'TierraDesktop',
    'out': './releases',
    'overwrite': true,
    'prune': true,
    'version': '1.3.4',
    'version-string': {
        'CompanyName': 'Paulo Galdo',
        'FileDescription': 'Tierra de colores', /*This is what display windows on task manager, shortcut and process*/
        'OriginalFilename': 'TierraDesktop',
        'ProductName': 'Tierra de colores',
        'InternalName': 'TierraDesktop'
    }
};
packager(options, function done_callback(err, appPaths) {
    console.log("Error: ", err);
    console.log("appPaths: ", appPaths);
});
```

Here you can see all the options you can use on this script: [link](https://github.com/electron/electron-packager/blob/master/usage.txt)

Comment: This script worked. Thank you very much! I don't know why CLI wasn't working. :/

Comment: nice, i've had the same problems with the CLI

Comment: @PauloGaldoSandoval The link is no longer used.

Answer (score -3):

You don't need `electron-packager`, `electron-builder` is enough as a complete solution, see https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder#quick-setup-guide

Comment: I tried builder too, and it also does nothing. I think it uses electron-packager, too, doesn't it?

Comment: Telling the OP to use a different packager would be a good answer if he were using the wrong one, but electron-packager is a perfectly acceptable way to do things, and it works for me. (I don't know the answer yet... still working on it.)

Comment: @MarcRochkind question tagged as `electron-builder` :)

Comment: @Luke Yes, electron-builder uses electron-packager, but under the hood, API is different. All configuration is done using `build` key in the `package.json`.